# sending email before 12 hours of specified time

Tags: php, email, time

I have to send an email to an employee regarding his meetings prior to 12 hours of the meeting time. The meeting time is stored in the mysql table. I should send the email using PHP. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, do a Cron job that searches for every record, takes it's time.

Then check if (time - 43200) is equal to current timestamp.
43200 seconds is 12 hours.

```
if (($time_from_db - 43200) === time())
{
    // send email
}
```

Comment: This is rather inefficient if you have many meetings to handle.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Unix-like platform, the system `at` queue is less resource-consuming than a regular `cron` job. Just schedule the job when you add the event to the database:

```
echo "echo 'Subject: meeting at $date' | sendmail '$user'" |
at "$(date -d "12 hours before $date")"
```

(Proof of concept; you probably want to do the date arithmetic in your host language, even if it's PHP.)

Take note of the queue number so you can remove it if the event is moved or cancelled.